# How can I stop python.exe from closing immediately after I get an output?

Tags: python

Is there any way I can stop python.exe from closing immediately after it completes? It closes faster than I can read the output.

Here is the program:

```
width = float(input("Enter the width: "))
height = float(input("Enter the height: "))
area = width * height
print("The area is", area, "square units.")
```

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. Are you using some IDE? Run it from the terminal.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can't - globally, i.e. for every python program. And this is a good thing - Python is great for scripting (automating stuff), and scripts should be able to run without any user interaction at all.

However, you can always ask for input at the end of your program, effectively keeping the program alive until you press return. Use [`input("prompt: ")` in Python 3](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#input) (or `raw_input("promt: ")` in Python 2). Or get used to running your programs from the command line (i.e. `python mine.py`), the program will exit but its output remains visible.

Answer (score 24):

Just declare a variable like `k` or `m` or any other you want, now just add this piece of code at the end of your program

```
k=input("press close to exit")
```

Here I just assumed `k` as variable to pause the program, you can use any variable you like.

Comment: Firstly, you don't "declare" - variable declaration in Python is implicit. Secondly, you there's no need to assign return value of the call to variable.

Comment: Beware that on error it will close it self right after the error message.

Answer (score 12):

For Windows Environments:

If you don't want to go to the command prompt (or work in an environment where command prompt is restricted), I think the following solution is better than inserting code into python that asks you to press any key - because if the program crashes before it reaches that point, the window closes and you lose the crash info. The solution I use is to create a bat file.

Use notepad to create a text file. In the file the contents will look something like:

```
my_python_program.py
pause
```

Then save the file as "my_python_program.bat"

When you run the bat file it will run the python program and pause at the end to allow you to read the output. Then if you press any key it will close the window.

Comment: The following .bat-file automatically runs a .py-file with the same name as the .bat-file. This make it easy to run multiple .py files - simply copy/paste/rename the .bat file for each .py-file:
`@ECHO OFF
"%cd%\%~n0%.py"
PAUSE>NUL`

Answer (score 7):

### Auxiliary answer

Manoj Govindan's answer is correct but I saw that comment:

> Run it from the terminal.

And got to thinking about why this is so not obvious to windows users and realized it's because CMD.EXE is such a poor excuse for a shell that it should start with:

> Windows command interpreter copyright 1999 Microsoft
>   Mein Gott!! Whatever you do, don't use this!!
>   C:>

Which leads me to point at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913912/bash-shell-for-windows

Comment: I have little exposure to non-windows OSs and their shells, but I realize bash is vastly superior to cmd. However, it's not as bad as some people claim - you can get basic stuff (navigating through the file system, invoking scripts and pre-built administration tools, etc) done. It's batch that really sucks. Plus, it has little to do with the question. Therefore, with a whispered "sorry", -1

Comment: +1. vaguely related and you make _great_ , if slightly unoriginal, points. don't let a sour windows user get you down: they're just jealous.

Comment: I've used JCL, CP/M, TOPS-10, and even VMS. The DOS CMD shell is really that bad. And although the point may be unoriginal, it was a bit of an epiphany to me that having to work with that interface likely actively discourages its use for the population generally (as it did for me when I've been forced by circumstance to use it).

Comment: The shells that come with Cygwin and MinGW both use the standard Windows console, which is tiny on any modern machine. I don't expect them to have a whole X server and good xterm, but being spoiled on real Linux, I find them inadequate. Windows Powershell is better, and you can run Python and all the MinGW stuff from it.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you are running something in Windows by double clicking on it. This will execute the program in a new window and close the window when it terminates. No wonder you cannot read the output.

A better way to do this would be to switch to the command prompt. Navigate (`cd`) to the directory where the program is located and then call it using `python`. Something like this:

```
C:\> cd C:\my_programs\
C:\my_programs\> python area.py
```

Replace `my_programs` with the actual location of your program and `area.py` with the name of your python file.

Comment: ok. that works but is there no way to just run area.py without it closing after it spits out "The area is X square units"? 
for example, the computers at my college dobt allow access to cmd.exe so how would i go about doing this. And ty for the timely responce.

Comment: "the computers at my college dobt allow access to cmd.exe" - Laughable at best. They allow you to run a python script but not use cmd.exe. Pitiful security.

Comment: @Clinton, you can use the `-i` flag to drop to a shell after a script is done. `python -i script.py`. This is very handy for debugging because you are in the namespace of the module defined by the script.

Comment: @mathepic... i totally agree.
@aaronasterling.... ty.

Answer (score 4):

Python files are executables, which means that you can run them directly from command prompt(assuming you have windows). You should be able to just enter in the directory, and then run the program.
Also, (assuming you have python 3), you can write:

```
input("Press enter to close program")
```

and you can just press enter when you've read your results.

Answer (score 1):

In windows, if Python is installed into the default directory (For me it is):

```
cd C:\Python27
```

You then proceed to type

```
"python.exe "[FULLPATH]\[name].py"
```

to run your Python script in Command Prompt