# Terminating python for loop program in the command line without closing it?

Tags: python, command-line-interface

When I open python 2.7.9 in the command terminal in Windows 8 and I run this program:

```
while True:

    for i in ["/","-","|","\\","|"]:

        print "%s\r" % i,
```

How can I terminate this program without closing the command terminal? I apologize in advance if this is a novice question but I'm still a rookie when it comes to programming and I rarely use the command terminal. Thanks! :)

Comment: See this one
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591807/how-can-i-stop-python-exe-from-closing-immediately-after-i-get-an-output

Comment: @SebastianWozny why would you refer the OP to a question that is itself a duplicate?

Comment: @SkipperDavies do you want to terminate it when a particular condition has been met?  at a particular time?  or just at your own whim (in which case `Ctrl+C` is probably the only option that makes sense)?  if not the latter, there are better ways to program in a termination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally I find that `Ctrl+c` does the job. It's a `keyboard interrupt` that should halt most python activity in the interpreter/terminal on both windows and linux