# Why is my python code running perfectly on Visual Studio but breaking in the terminal?

Tags: python, visual-studio, terminal, visual-studio-2019, command-prompt

Very new programmer here! Can someone please help me understand what's happening with my python code?

```
def Validate_Integer_Input(prompt):

global strFlag
global value
while strFlag is False:
    try:
        value = int(input(prompt))
    except ValueError:
        print("Input must be numeric.")
        continue

    if value < 0:
        print("Integer must be positive. ")
        continue
    else:
        strFlag = True 
return value

def Calculate_Sphere_Volume(intDiameter):
dblVolume = float(0)
dblRadius = float(0)

global strFlag
strFlag = bool(False)
intDiameter = Validate_Integer_Input("Please enter diameter of sphere: ")

dblRadius = float(intDiameter / 2)

import math
dblVolume = (4/3 * math.pi * (dblRadius**3))
print("The volume of a sphere with a diameter of ", intDiameter, " has a volume of", dblVolume)
```

When I run the code in Visual Studio, it is working perfectly, printing out the correct volume. When I run the program on the Windows terminal, after I enter the diameter the terminal just disappears. Can someone help me understand why this is happening??! Much appreciated!!

(Main code just calls the Calculate_Sphere_Volume function)

Comment: Duplicate of [How can I stop python.exe from closing immediately after I get an output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591807/how-can-i-stop-python-exe-from-closing-immediately-after-i-get-an-output)

Comment: add input()  after all of the code

Comment: Wow. I've been going crazy over this for an hour. Thanks!!