# Terminal pop-up window closes

Tags: python, terminal, popup, visual-studio-code

I'm starting coding with python, but and I want to execute my program in a terminal pop-up window in vscode. The problem is that when I open the terminal `View > Terminal` and type `.\helloworld.py` it appears a pop-up window but when the code ends, it closes immediatly. I just want that the windows stays opened

The code ends because it's just a `print("Hello World")`

I'm looking if there's a configuration in the terminal like a .json that do not close the windows even though the program has end if it is posible (I know I can make an `input("")`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I stop python.exe from closing immediately after I get an output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591807/how-can-i-stop-python-exe-from-closing-immediately-after-i-get-an-output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If just `print("Hello World")` in your code, you may try adding `"console":"externalTerminal"` in [launch.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_initialize-configurations), then **Run> Run without Debugging** to get code executed in the external Terminal:

[image]