# Need Help about converting .py to .exe

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe, auto-py-to-exe

```
score = []
percent = []
add = []

print("Enter Grade") 

#getting input from user
def multi_input():
    try:
        while True:
            data=input()
            if not data: break
            yield data
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        return

data = list(multi_input())

#filter data into percent and score
for i in range(3, len(data),4):
    data[i] = data[i].split('\t')
    try:
        percent.append(data[i][3])
        score.append(data[i][4])
    except IndexError:
        result = 0

#take out ungraded values
percent = [value for value in percent if value != '']
score = [value for value in score if value != '']

#refine percent data
for i in range(len(percent)):
    try:
        percent[i] = percent[i].replace('%', '')
        percent[i] = float(percent[i])
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        result = 0

#refine score data
for i in range(len(score)):
    score[i] = score[i].split('/')
    for j in range(len(score[i])):
        score[i][j] = float(score[i][j])
    try:
        score[i] = score[i][0]/score[i][1]*100
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        result = 0

#amount of assignments
print()
print("graded assignments: ", len(score))

#calculation
for i in range(len(score)):
    add.append(score[i]*percent[i]/100)

print(f"{sum(add)/sum(percent)*100:05.2f}")
```

This code should print the GPA of this input/data after pressing enter two times:

Oct
12
Tests
Test 2      B   18.3%   41/50       10/12/22
Oct
05
Labs & Projects
Plant Pigments      A   15% 9/10        10/7/22
Sep
28
Homework/Assignments
Leaf Anatomy        A   2.6%    20/20       9/28/22
Sep
23
Homework/Assignments
Osmosis     A   3.4%    26/26       10/21/22
Sep
21
Tests
Test 1      B   21.7%   47.5/59     9/23/22
Sep
21
Homework/Assignments
Cell Diagrams       A   2.6%    20/20       9/28/22
Sep
07
Labs & Projects
Lab: Identifying Macromolecules     A   15% 12/10       9/21/22
Sep
07
Homework/Assignments
Properties of Water     A   4%  30/30       9/14/22
Sep
05
Homework/Assignments
Enzymes: Practice What You Know     A   2%  15/15       9/14/22
Aug
26
Homework/Assignments
Macromolecules Chart        A   2.6%    20/20       9/11/22
Aug
22
Homework/Assignments
Scientific Investment Practice      B   2.6%    16/20       9/13/22

It works perfectly on Pycharm, but when converted to .exe by pyinstaller or autopytoexe, the console screen just closes instead of printing the result.

HELP

I have no idea of where this error comes from since in some platform it works while others do not

Comment: "closes instead of printing the result" - more likely, it prints the result very quickly and then exits because it has nothing more to do. You can insert `input()` at the end of your script to make your code wait for the user to input something and terminate the program.

Answer (score 0):

The .exe file runs your script, but after it runs it, nothing tells it to keep the window open, so it closes it.

You can try as a very quick solution to add

```
k = input("press close to exit")
```

at the end of your script to prompt for input so it doesn't close.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591807/how-can-i-stop-python-exe-from-closing-immediately-after-i-get-an-output) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000900/how-to-keep-a-python-script-output-window-open)